# Passing a python generic to parent class?

Tags: python-3.x, generics, type-hinting

I have a parent class which is declared as a generic, an abstract subclass and a concrete implementation of that subclass, which declares the generic type:

```
MyType = TypeVar('MyType')

class A(Generic[MyType]):
   a: MyType

class B(Generic[MyType], A[MyType]):
   pass

class C(B[int]):
   pass
```

But this doesn't forward the generic declaration from C to A, so the type of a is not int. Is there a correct way to do this? Tried searching both SO and python docs but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `A` you have a class variable, so it is shared amongst all instances of the class. If you try and type hint this you have a conflict anytime you create a new sub-class of `A`.

For instance what type does `a` have here:

```py
class A(Generic[MyType]):
   a: MyType

class A1(A[str]):
   pass

class A2(A[int]):
   pass
```

If you want to represent a member variable on `A` then you can do it like this:

```py
class A(Generic[MyType]):
    def __init__(self, a: MyType):
        self.val = a


class B(Generic[MyType], A[MyType]):
    def __init__(self, b: MyType):
        A.__init__(self, b)


class C(B[int]):
    def __init__(self, c: int):
        B.__init__(self, c)


class D(B[str]):
    def __init__(self, d: str):
        B.__init__(self, d)
```

Here we have two classes `C` and `D which both have different generics` int`and`str` and the type hinting works because we are creating sub-classes which have different generics on them.

Hope after 6 months this might help :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from @henry-b is wrong on a few points.

1. `a` in the example is *not* a class variable, because it is not assigned to anything. It is only added to `A.__annotations__`.
2. Because of (1), `A1.a` and `A2.a` (and similarly `C.a` and `D.a` in the second example) already have different types. There is nothing to worry about.
3. Although the abstract subclass `B` in the original example doesn't "forward" the generic declaration, this is already true even for a direct concrete subclass:

```
class A(Generic[T]):
    a: T

class C(A[int]):
   pass

inspect.get_annotations(A)  # {'a': ~T}
inspect.get_annotations(B)  # {}
```

Breaking down the solution in the accepted answer, it does two things:

1. Create an instance variable `val` (I'll call it `a` for consistency with the original question)
2. Make the subclasses' `__init__` functions "inspect"-able with the implementation type.

We can write that in a cleaner way:

```
# This is a pure abstract class, so it shouldn't have __init__
class A(Generic[T]):
    a: T

class B(Generic[T], A[T]):
    def __init__(self, a: T):
        self.a = a

class C(B[int]):
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        super().__init__(a)

class D(B[str]):
    pass

# As mentioned above, if we inspect `C.__init__` we get the impl type,
# while for `D.__init__` it's still the generic type:
inspect.get_annotations(C.__init__)  # {'a': <class 'int'>}
inspect.get_annotations(D.__init__)  # {'a': ~T}
```

What the accepted answer does *not* do is what it claims to do: "forward" the type annotation from the concrete class to the abstract ancestor class (i.e., answer the question). The instance variable `a` is still the generic type:

```
C(1).__annotations__      # {'a': ~T}
D('foo').__annotations__  # {'a': ~T}
```

And it doesn't matter anyway; PyType can catch invalid types either way:

```
c = C(1)      # fine
d = D('foo')  # fine

c = C('foo')  # pytype throws 'wrong-arg-types'
d = D(1)      # pytype throws 'wrong-arg-types'
```

If you do want the concrete class to have inspect-able types for the instance attribute, you have to annotate it again:

```
class E(B[bool]):
    a: bool
    def __init__(self, a: bool):
        super().__init__(a)
```